# Find Value Using Selenium using a Variable that Contains String

Tags: python

I am trying to open up several URL's (because they contain data I want to append to a list). I have a logic saying `"if amount in icl_dollar_amount_l"` then run the rest of the code. However, I want the script to only run the rest of the code on that specific amount in the variable `"amount"`.

Example:

selenium opens up X amount of links and sees `['144,827.95', '5,199,024.87', '130,710.67']` in `icl_dollar_amount_l` but i want it to skip `'144,827.95'`, `'5,199,024.87'` and only get the information for `'130,710.67'` which is in the `'amount'` variable already.

Actual results:

Its getting webscaping information for amount `'144,827.95'` only and not even going to `'5,199,024.87'`, `'130,710.67'`. I only want it getting webscaping information for `'130,710.67'` because my amount variable has this as the only amount.

```
print(icl_dollar_amount_l)

['144,827.95', '5,199,024.87', '130,710.67']

print(amount)

'130,710.67'
```

file2.py

```
def scrapeBOAWebsite(url,fcg_subject_l, gp_subject_l):

    from ICL_Awk_Checker import  rps_amount_l2

    icl_dollar_amount_l = []
    amount_ack_missing_l = []
    file_total_l = []
    body_l = []


    for link in url:
        print(link)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                                   executable_path=r'\\TEST\user$\TEST\Documents\driver\chromedriver.exe')
        # if 'P2 Cust ID 908554 File' in fcg_subject:
        browser.get(link)
        username = browser.find_element_by_name("dialog:username").get_attribute('value')
        submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dialog:continueButton']").click()
        body = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Total:')]").text
        body_l.append(body)
        icl_dollar_amount = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$', 1)[1]
        icl_dollar_amount_l.append(icl_dollar_amount)
     if not missing_amount:
        logging.info("List is empty")
        print("List is empty")
     count = 0
     for amount in missing_amount:
        if amount in icl_dollar_amount_l:
            body = body_l[count]
            get_file_total = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$', 1)[1]
            file_total_l.append(get_file_total)

    return icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l, company_id_l, client_id_l, customer_name_l, file_name_l, file_total_l, \
           item_count_l, file_status_l, amount_ack_missing_l
```

Comment: I don't understand it

Comment: maybe instead of `if amount in icl_dollar_amount_l:` use `for item in icl_dollar_amount_l: if item == amount: ...` and maybe you should keep values togeter as pairs `(body, icl_dollar_amount)` instead of separaded lists because now you will need `zip(body_l, icl_dollar_amount_l)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but this

```
 if amount in icl_dollar_amount_l:
```

doesn't give information on which position is `'130,710.67'` in `icl_dollar_amount_l` and you need also

```
 count = icl_dollar_amount_l.index(amount)
```

---

```
for amount in missing_amount:
    if amount in icl_dollar_amount_l:
        count = icl_dollar_amount_l.index(amount)
        body = body_l[count]
```

---

But it will works if you expect only one `amount` on list `icl_dollar_amount_l`. For more elements you would have to use rather `for`-loop and check every element separatelly

```
for amount in missing_amount:
    for count, item in enumerate(icl_dollar_amount_l)
        if amount == item :
             body = body_l[count]
```

But frankly I don't know why you don't check it in first loop `for link in url:` when you have direct access to `icl_dollar_amount` and `body`

Comment: Thanks! This works but now i get duplicated 130,710.67 when i print it because its under two for loops.

Comment: if you means two separated `for`-loop then question is why you use two separated `for`-loop, why not use only one

Comment: because i need to loop through my url's in the first loop, and the second one i need to access item by item in the list missing_amount.

Comment: if you get two values `130,710.67` then maybe you get it on pages. And you have to decide which one to choose. I can't run your code with your urls and data so I can't say what can be problem.

Comment: I opened the URL pages and its only one amount for  130,710.67. I think this has to do because of two for loops under each other.

Comment: you can use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. you didn't create minimal working code (with real data) which we could simply copy and run - so we can't help you more. You have to debug it on your own.